# BigQuery issue: how & why the timestamp can be the same for the same visitor?

Tags: google-analytics, duplicates, google-bigquery, unix-timestamp

I'm facing the following issue with the timestamp field for 'visitStartTime' in BigQuery for the same visitor accessing to the website through 2 different browsers ?
How & why is it possible (the timestamp should be changing becasue the seconds are normally calculated with the timestamp based on a positive number specifies the number of seconds since the unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC)?

Query that produced the results in screenshot:

```
SELECT
  DATE,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN customDimensions.index = 1 THEN customDimensions.value END) AS CUSTOMDIMENSIONS_VALUE,  visitNumber,  fullvisitorid,  visitStartTime,  SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime) AS humain,  TIME (visitStartTime+3600 ) AS Paris_timezone,  hits.hour,  hits.minute,  CONCAT(fullvisitorid, STRING(visitid)) AS sessionid,  MAX(CASE
      WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 11 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS localproductname,
  device.deviceCategory,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel2, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,
  IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel3, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 14 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS assetpurpose,
  hits.hitNumber,
FROM (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20161025], customDimensions.value )),
  (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20161026], customDimensions.value )),
WHERE
  AND customDimensions.value != "null"
  AND customDimensions.value = "968a9587-0614-4155-9597-bf17aef42125"
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
  AND (customDimensions.index = 1
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 11
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 14
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 27 )
GROUP EACH BY
  DATE,
  visitStartTime,
  humain,
  Paris_timezone,
  hits.hour,
  hits.minute,
  fullVisitorId,
  sessionid,
  visitNumber,
  device.deviceCategory,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,
  HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3,
  hits.hitNumber,
LIMIT
  100000
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Based on column names, I assume you got this data from Google Analytics (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en). The documentation says that

> Each row within a table corresponds to a session in Google Analytics
>   360.

Therefore `visitStartTime` corresponds to the start of the session. It is not clear from your attached screenshot whether rows flattening has happened, but if it did - this will explain it.

Comment: Thank you Mosha, I will add a query example; it may help you.

Comment: SELECT
  DATE,
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN customDimensions.index = 1 THEN customDimensions.value END) AS CUSTOMDIMENSIONS_VALUE,  visitNumber,  fullvisitorid,  visitStartTime, SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime) AS humain, TIME (visitStartTime+3600 ) as Paris_timezone, hits.hour,  hits.minute,     
      CONCAT(fullvisitorid, STRING(visitid)) AS sessionid,
      MAX(CASE

Comment: WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 11 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS localproductname, device.deviceCategory,  hits.page.pagePath,  IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel2, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,  IFNULL(hits.page.pagePathLevel3, '') AS HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3, 
  MAX(CASE
      WHEN hits.customDimensions.index = 14 THEN hits.customDimensions.value END) AS assetpurpose,  
  hits.hitNumber,
FROM (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20161025], customDimensions.value )), 
(FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20161026], customDimensions.value )),

Comment: WHERE
  AND customDimensions.value != "null"
  AND customDimensions.value = "968a9587-0614-4155-9597-bf17aef42125"
  AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
  AND (customDimensions.index = 1
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 11
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 14
    OR hits.customDimensions.index = 27 )
GROUP EACH BY
  DATE,
  visitStartTime,
  humain,
  Paris_timezone,
  hits.hour,
  hits.minute,
  fullVisitorId,
  sessionid,
  visitNumber,
  device.deviceCategory,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL2,
  HITS_PAGE_PAGEPATHLEVEL3,
  hits.hitNumber,
LIMIT
  100000

Comment: @sPujade - please do not use comments to show your code  - just add it to your original question!

Comment: Thank you @Mosha Pasumansky. So do you assume, the results may be different if I did not apply flatten as an option? But I thought that by default BQL was displaying results with flattening parameters. Am I right? Thank so much for your help